# Convert date time into specified format in PostgreSQL query

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, datetime, date-formatting

For converting datetime into SQL Server CE, I am using below format

```
var date = "CONVERT(datetime,'" + 
((DateTime) DateTime.UtcNow).ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-us")) 
+ "',112)";
```

For Oracle:

```
var date = "TO_DATE('" 
+ ((DateTime)DateTime.UtcNow).ToString("MMddyyyy hh:mm:ss tt") 
+ "', 'mmddyyyy hh:mi:ss')";
```

And for MySQL:

```
var date = "STR_TO_DATE('" 
+ ((DateTime)DateTime.UtcNow).ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-us")) 
+ "','%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s')";
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert the same in **PostgreSQL**?

**Note:** I am using `timestamp` datatype

Comment: [Date/Time Input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) and [`to_date`/`to_timestamp` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `to_char` function to format a timestamp:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comments, the same call could be applied in an `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
(formatted_timestamp_column, some_other_column)
VALUES (TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'some_value')
```

Comment: I need to insert via the data time value. Can you please suggest this in insert query ?

Comment: @Shesha The same call could just be applied there. See, e.g., my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a very simple approach, you can also use this:

```
var date = $"'{new NpgsqlDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow)}'";
```

Edit: This has been deprecated since version 7.* of Npgsql. See this: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2009

Answer (score 1):

With PostgreSQL, you can use the code from Oracle, just take `to_timestamp` instead of `to_date`.

The difference is that `date`in PostgreSQL is a *real* date and not a timestamp with second precision like it is in Oracle.
So while you can use `to_date` as you do above, the result will not have any time information.

By, the way, your Oracle format is wrong. You probably want to use `HH24` and not `HH` for the "hour" part.